# Dynamically increase/decrease array size

Tags: c, arrays, size, append

I'm trying to increase the size of an array dynamically. Is there any standard C or C++ function, which appends additional space at the end of an array or removes it?
I know, this is difficult, since it cannot be assured that there is enough space at the end on the heap. But shouldn't this be the job of an operating system?

Comment: [`void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) function in C

Comment: You need to make up your mind as to what language you are programming in. In C you'd use `realloc`. In C++ you'd use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) in C, which is also present in the C++ STL as [`std::realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc)

Though as you mentioned C++, you could also go for an standard container like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which encapsulate the associated memory management.

Comment: it doesn't  decease size, does it **?**

Comment: well, it does decrease if I enter a smaller size than I previously had. Or is this not possible?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You can specify a new size inferior to the old size of the array. The C Standard specifies (7.20.3.4) that `realloc()` "deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size" and that the content of the new object is the same up to min(oldSize, newSize).

Comment: Further on size; if the new size is larger than the old one, the memory whose address is returned from realloc()

Answer (score 0):

There is no C functions as such. you can go for C++ container. This has Arrays, lists etc...

Answer (score 0):

probably you can achieve this by writing your own memory management wrapper such a way to append/release memory chunks from allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation by folks like professors and engineers (that have real jobs over some number of years,) when expanding an array, expand it by 50% unless you have inside information that tells you different. realloc() does all the **heavy lifting** for you too (explained next.) **From the Internet:-->** The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes. The contents will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes. If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized. If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr). Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.