# Increasing the size of an array during runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, dynamic

I want to dynamically allocate an array in a for loop using pointers. As the for loop proceeds, the size of the array should increase by one and a new element should be added then. The usual method involves using the `new` operator, but this always allocated a fixed memory at the time of declaration. Is there any way to do so?

I tried to do so using the following code (simplified for explaing the problem):

```
sameCombsCount = 0;
int **matchedIndicesArray;    
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) //loop condition a variable
{
  sameCombsCount++;

  matchedIndicesArray = new int*[sameCombsCount]; // ??
  // Now add an element in the new block created...
}
```

The thing is, I do not know the size of the for loop during execution time. It can vary depending upon execution conditions and inputs given. I don't think this is the correct way to do so. Can someone suggest a way to do so?

Comment: If you want an array where the size can change you want a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: `std::vector` does this for you. If you want to implement this on your own, you will have to reallocate memory when you need more.

Comment: That's not an array. That's a pointer to a pointer. You should prefer the vector to raw arrays or pointers as suggested above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically increase/decrease array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689847/dynamically-increase-decrease-array-size)

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` handles the resizing for you:

```
sameCombsCount = 0;
std::vecotr<int> matchedIndicesArray;    
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) //loop condition a variable
{
  sameCombsCount++;

#if 0
  matchedIndicesArray.resize(sameCombsCount);
  matchedIndicesArray.back() = someValue;
#else
  matchedIndicesArray.push_back(someValue);
#endif
}
```

The first version does what you wanted and resizes the vector then sets the value. The second version just adds the element directly at the end of the array and should be marginally more efficient.